# Applying SSL in Tomcat UnsatisfiedLinkError Issue

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I'm trying to make http protocol into https protocol

To do this, I noticed that I need to apply SSL in tomcat.

[install an SSL/TLS in Tomcat](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/tomcat-ssl-installation/)

I didn't follow this site but proceeded similarly.

First of all, I created .keystore then .crt

Then, I entered

`<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keyAlias="tomcat_ssl" keystoreFile="E:/OpenSSL/bin/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="xxxxxxxxx" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>`

in server.xml

After I restarted tomcat, when I tried to enter in http://localhost:8080, it shows the website.

However, when I tried to enter in https://localhost:8443, it made error like this.

> August 18, 2022 2:22:38 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor doRun
> Fatal:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.renegotiatePending(J)I
> at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.renegotiatePending(Native Method)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.getHandshakeStatus(OpenSSLEngine.java:1068)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.wrap(OpenSSLEngine.java:475)
> at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeWrap(SecureNioChannel.java:474)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:218)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1648)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I'm using tomcat 8.5.73 and jdk as 1.8.0_281

Is there any solution for this error?

Comment: Looks like the Tomcat native library needs to be updated.

Comment: @Olivier I will try that and leave a comment for you Thx for suggestion

Comment: @Olivier I deleted the library and installed with new version but same error pops up....

Comment: Do you *want* to use the native library, or the plain-Java TLS connector? Plain-Java is less hassle. Your configuration looks very out-of-date as you are not using `<SSLHostConfig>` in there.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz there are several options in server.xml which are 

<Connector xxxxxxx
   <UpgradeProtocol/>
   <SSLHostConfig/>
</Connector>

should I use this??

Comment: @StevePark I'm not sure I understand your question. The originally-posted question has only `<Connector/>` and no sub-elements. Newer configurations for TLS should have a `<Connector>` with one or more `<SSLHostConfig>` sub-elements. It's more expressive that way, clearer what you are trying to do, and allow virtual-host-based certificate-selection (which is not possible using the `<Connector/>`-only configuration).

Comment: You need to make sure that the version of the Tomcat Native dll matches the version of OpenSSL installed. To check, open a command line and type `openssl version`. Then, check that you are using APR 1.2.x with OpenSSL 1.1.x or APR 2.x if you are using OpenSSL 3.x (as of March 2023). If you try to use APR with the wrong OpenSSL version, you get the "unsatisfied link error".